# Convergence in probability exercise 2

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_{n}$, $n \in \{1,2,...\}$. If the density of $X_{n}$ are
> $f_{n} =
> \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   \frac{n\cos(nx)}{\sin(n\theta)}  & \mbox{if } 0 < x < \theta \mbox{, with } \theta \in (0, \pi/2)  \\
>   0 & \mbox{otherwise} 
>  \end{array}
> \right.$

> See if $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $\theta$.

So far I've tried:

> $P(|X_{n} - \theta| > \epsilon) = P(\theta - \epsilon>  X_{n} > \theta + \epsilon) = P(X_{n} \in (\theta - \epsilon, \theta)) + P(X_{n} \in [\theta, \theta + \epsilon))$

> I know this last probability is $0$, so $P(|X_{n} - \theta| > \epsilon) = P(X_{n} \in (\theta - \epsilon, \theta))$.

I don't know if what I did was right or if it even is the way to start the exercise. If someone could help I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The first equality is wrong. Apply that $$|a|\geq\epsilon\iff a>\epsilon\text{ or }a<-\epsilon$$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

So using the hint from @drhab, we can write for every $\epsilon > 0$,

\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n - \theta\rvert > \epsilon) &= \mathbb{P}(\{X_n - \theta > \epsilon\} \cup \{X_n - \theta \leq \epsilon\}) \\[0.6em]
    &= \mathbb{P}(X_n > \theta + \epsilon) + \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq \theta + \epsilon)\\[0.6em]
    &= \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq \theta + \epsilon), \hspace{20mm} \text{since } X_n \leq \theta,\\[0.6em]
    &= \int_{}^{} \frac{n\cos(n x)}{sin(n\theta)}dx,\\
    &=\frac{n}{\sin(n\theta)}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sin(n x)\right]_{0}^{\theta - \epsilon}, \\[0.6em]
    &= \frac{\sin(n(\theta - \epsilon))}{\sin(n\theta)}.
\end{align}
So then,
\begin{align}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}(\lvert X_n - \theta\rvert > \epsilon) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sin(n(\theta - \epsilon))}{\sin(n\theta)},
\end{align}
which does not converge for any $\epsilon > 0$. Therefore, $X_n$ does not converge in probability.